# PHP radio button check if null

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

So we get this school task where we need to check if one of the fields is unfilled and display an error. We did this but for some strange reason it doesn't display a error when a radio button is unchecked (a textfield null check works fine).

I've tried with a friend many possibilities but they all don't seem to work. We have been stuck at this task for two hours. Now we have tried making separate `if`'s but that doesn't seem to work too.

These are the important parts:

```
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="taal" value="false">
    Choose a language
<input type="radio" name="taal" value="N"> Dutch
<input type="radio" name="taal" value="E"> English
<input type="radio" name="taal" value="S"> Spanish
```

```
if (@$_POST['taal'] == null){
echo "No Language gotten";
return;
}
```

Comment: Suppressing errors is not recommended. Use `if (!isset($_POST['taal']))` instead.

Comment: `if (empty($_POST['taal'])) { ... }` and make `value=""` for the hidden input. PS: `var_dump($_POST);` - this would answer all your questions without wasting your time

Comment: It was clear in this case, but I would recommend avoid using the phrase 'it doesn't work' - it is better to explain what you expected, and what you actually got `:)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can omit the hidden tag:

```
Choose a language
<input type="radio" name="taal" value="N"> Dutch
<input type="radio" name="taal" value="E"> English
<input type="radio" name="taal" value="S"> Spanish
```

And use `isset()` to check whether the value was sent. If none of the radio buttons are checked, `taal` will simply not be added to the posted data. So you have to check for whether it was set or not, you can do this with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if (!isset($_POST['taal'])){
    echo "No Language gotten";
    return;
}
```

Also, in most cases, it is recommended **not** to use the [`@` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Error messages (warnings, notices, etc.) are there to warn you about a problem in your code. Fix the problem instead of hiding it, or it might come back and bite you later.

Comment: This fully fixed my problem. The hidden tag was the problem after all. So i guess my school books have to be rewritten! (Ill choose your answers as best in 8min(I cant do it earlyer..))

Comment: @Dallox I've seen a lot of schoolbooks that should not have been written at all.

Comment: Yeh our book is probbaly one of them. Got loads and loads of mistakes. We might be better of learning from the internet..

Comment: @Dallox In most cases the Internet is even worse. There are loads of outdated and terrible PHP tutorials that teach you practices you should never use - you should be very careful. On StackOverflow the situation is much better though. And the PHP Manual is very recommended to read thoroughly and habitually.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!isset($_POST['taal']))  {
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because it will never be empty. You gave it a default value, `"false"`. Check against that:

```
if ($_POST['taal'] == "false") {
   //No language given
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value 'false' in your hidden element is a string, so you should compare `$_POST['taal'] == 'false'` for it to work.

It'd probably be better setting this false element to an empty string, and then compare it with `''`. Also, I don't recommend using `@` to suppress warnings, so try this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['taal']) || !$_POST['taal']) { ...
```

Comment: `$_POST['taal'] == ''` looks a bit better written as `!$_POST['taal']`